# how to program PRU of beaglebone black in C

Tags: beagleboneblack

I want to try blinking a led on PRU core of beaglebone black rev c.The program I want to write is in c language and o.s. is ubuntu without emulator as described in TI's hands on labs for pru.
I tried blinking led program with TI am335x cortex-A8.
I want to try same with PRU.
I am confused with the dependencies required by PRU. 
Any suggestions or guideline will be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this example to blink the a led. It is working on my side.

```
https://github.com/beagleboard/am335x_pru_package/blob/master/pru_sw/old_example/PRU_gpioToggle/
```

Also please, review the git repository:

```
https://github.com/beagleboard/am335x_pru_package
```

Comment: thank you for your reply....does it work on same cross compiler that we used for am335x cortex-A8?

Comment: The CPU architecture is the close the each other. I have used PRU system with beaglebone for linux cnc. Also if you need a tutorial from strach. you can use this example.    http://ianrrees.github.io/2016/11/20/getting-started-with-beaglebone-pru-programming-the-new-way.html In addition, if this answers meets your expectation you can click on completed button

Comment: thank you for the help I will prefer to start from scratch.